# Save Google Doc to Xml

Tags: xml, xmlwriter, google-docs

So, I am trying very hard to save a google doc spreadsheet to an xml using the SpreadsheetEntry.SaveToXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter) but I am getting the following error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
Additional information: The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' within the same start element tag.

My code is below, I am almost certain that I am using the API correctly...can someone tell me how to fix this error? It creates the file okay, but it never writes anything to it.

```
    public void backUpSpreadsheets()
    {
        SpreadsheetFeed allSpreadSheets = this.allSheets;

        foreach(SpreadsheetEntry sheet in this.allSheets.Entries)
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Users\BagpipesJohnson\Desktop\testing\" + sheet.Title.Text + ".xml"))
                sheet.SaveToXml(writer);
        }
    }
```

Thanks